# Escaped apostrophe causing issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Okay ... I always thought that escaping apostrophe would allow you to use it in a JavaScript string and not break your quotes.

However, I have the following JavaScript call:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteAgenda(2056, 'PJ&#39;s Happy 4th of July New Agenda', '7/20/2017 5:15:00 PM');">
```

And I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

It fails in both Chrome and IE.

If I make the same call without the escaped apostrophe, it works.

If I cannot use an escaped apostrophe in a JavaScript String, how am I supposed to escape it?

Thanks,

Philip

Comment: The easiest way to avoid this kind of trouble is to stop using inline javascript. onclicks are so '90s...

Comment: @georg Alternatives?

Comment: Since you appear to be using bootstrap and hence jquery, try http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are attempting to use **[HTML character entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)** from within JavaScript. All you need to do to escape an apostrophe in JavaScript is to preface the apostrophe with a backslash (`'PJ\'s ... '`):

```js
function deleteAgenda(one, two) {
  console.log(two);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteAgenda(2056, 'PJ\'s Happy 4th of July New Agenda', '7/20/2017 5:15:00 PM');">Hi there</a>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it!  Implementing it was painful since I'm writing this through C#, so I triple-escaped my backslashes to get it to work but that fixed it!